# clone array and add a subarray

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, clone

i have the following problem. i have a large array structure which i assign values from a sql statement:

```
$data[$user][$month]['id'] = $data->id;
$data[$user][$month]['company'] = $data->company;
...
...
```

and around 30 other values.

i need to clone this array ($data) and add a subarray like:

```
$data[$user][$month][$newsubarray]['id'] = $data->id;
$data[$user][$month][$newsubarray]['company'] = $data->company;
...
...
```

i need to clone it because the original array is used by many templates to display data.

is there a way to clone the array and add the subarray without assign all the values to the cloned array? this blows up my code and is very newbi, but works.

Comment: `$data[$user][$month][$newsubarray] = $data[$user][$month];` Something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through the array with nested [foreach loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

It would look similar to this:

```
foreach ($data as $user=>$arr2) {
    foreach ($arr2 as $month=>$arr3) {
        foreach ($arr3 as $key=>$value) {
            $data[$user][$month][$newsubarray][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this worked, had to exclude 2 values because they have a summary. thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_map, check the [live demo](https://eval.in/798416)

if you want to pass parameter to array_map(), use this

```
array_map(function($v) use($para1, $para2, ...){...}, $array);
```

Here is the code,

```
<?php

$array =array('user'=> array('month'=>array('id' =>2, 'company' => 3)));
print_r($array);
print_r(array_map(function($v){
  $arr = $v['month'];
  $v['month'] = [];
  $v['month']['newsubarray'] = $arr;
  return $v;}
, $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last level of array, you can create object, for holding data with implementing `ArrayAccess`. Then simply by reference, assign object in desire places. This way, you can hold 1 object and use it multi places, but if you change in one - this change in all.

Then you addictionaly, can implements `__clone` method to clone object correctly.